# How to get unique value of json and sum another value in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have one json value in that json file three movie's name. JSON data are dynamic data. I want to calculate percentage on `WinProbability` field. I want output as follows

```
movie_name = [ "12 Years a Slave", "American Hustle", "Captain"]
percentage = [ 3.47, 2.54, 4.22]
```

My JSON file shown

```
[
    {
        "ID":1,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":0.00,"WinType":"Win"
    },
    {
        "ID":2,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":2.81,"WinType":"Win"
    },
    {   
        "ID":3,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":0.66,"WinType":"Nominated"
    },
    {   
        "ID":1,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":1.62,"WinType":"Nominated"
    },
    {
        "ID":2,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":0.85,"WinType":"Win"
    },
    {
        "ID":3,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":0.07,"WinType":"Win"
    },
    {   
        "ID":1,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":2.70,"WinType":"Nominated"
    },
    {
        "ID":2,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":0.00,"WinType":"Win"
    },
    {   
        "ID":3,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":1.52,"WinType":"Win"
    }
]
```

My jquery code

```
$(function() {  
    $.getJSON('movie.json', function(data) {                

                var movie_name = [],
                    percentage = [];

                data.forEach(function(obj) {
                    if (movie_name.indexOf(obj.Nominee) == -1)
                        movie_name.push(obj.Nominee);

                    var lastIndex = movie_name.length - 1;       
                    if (typeof percentage[lastIndex] == "undefined")
                        percentage.push(obj.WinProbability);
                    else
                        percentage[lastIndex] += obj.WinProbability; 
                });

                console.log(movie_name);
                console.log(percentage);

            });
});
```

Please help me how to do this. I tried make unique name of nominee but I don't know to add `WinProbability` and calculate percentage.

Possible to change data into below format

```
    {
    "Win": [
        {
            "0": 3.47,
            "name": "12 Years a Slave"
        },{
            "0": 2.54,
            "name": "American Hustle"
        },{
            "0": 4.22,
            "name": "Captain Phillips"
        }
    ],
    "Nominated":[
        {
            "0": 1.2,
            "name": "12 Years a Slave"
        },{
            "0": 1,
            "name": "American Hustle"
        },{
            "0": 1,
            "name": "Captain Phillips"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think your calculation is wrong. Sum of `12 Years a Slave` should be `3.47`

Comment: @Mohammad Yes acutlly i put dummy value

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: @Mohammad i updated my question and inert jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check existence of value in array using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). If value doesn't exist in array, insert it using [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). About `WinProbability`, if exist, increase value of it.

```js
 var json = [
    {"ID":1,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":0.00,"WinType":"Win"},
    {"ID":2,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":2.81,"WinType":"Win"},
    {"ID":3,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":0.66,"WinType":"Nominated"},
    {"ID":1,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":1.62,"WinType":"Nominated"},
    {"ID":2,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":0.85,"WinType":"Win"},
    {"ID":3,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":0.07,"WinType":"Win"},
    {"ID":1,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":2.70,"WinType":"Nominated"},
    {"ID":2,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":0.00,"WinType":"Win"},
    {"ID":3,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":1.52,"WinType":"Win"}
];

var movie_name = [],
    percentage = [];
  
json.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (movie_name.indexOf(obj.Nominee) == -1)
        movie_name.push(obj.Nominee);
    
    var lastIndex = movie_name.length - 1;       
    if (typeof percentage[lastIndex] == "undefined")
        percentage.push(obj.WinProbability);
    else
        percentage[lastIndex] += obj.WinProbability; 
});

console.log(movie_name);
console.log(percentage);
```

Comment: percentage not working get undefinde
Array [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 68 more… ]

Comment: But i am use this code inside the $.getJSON('movie.json', function(data) { your code });

Comment: Your JSON result is in `data` variable. Do you changed `json` variable name in my code to `data`?

Comment: Yes, i changed json to data

Comment: @dhanashri If it doesn't work, maybe your browser version is old.

Comment: Maybe `data` value if empty. Check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118146/discussion-between-dhanashri-and-mohammad).

Comment: if i am alert typeof percentage[lastIndex] get undefinded

Comment: Check `data` variable is not empty.

Comment: data variable is not empty bcoz get proper data from movie_name but percentage not working
Array [ "12 Years a Slave", "American Hustle", "Captain Phillips", "Dallas Buyers Club", "Gravity", "Her", "Nebraska", "Philomena", "The Wolf of Wall Street" ]

Comment: Check your json is like my json. Does exist `WinProbability` value in your json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118359/discussion-between-dhanashri-and-mohammad).

Comment: can we change the data format  i mention in the question